# Ubuntu VM pinging each other with Internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.10, ping

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and installed the Virtualbox from the Ubuntu Software Center.
Later on, I installed three (3) Windows XP Virtual Machines. I'm trying to get all of the three VMs to ping each other for me to test a client/server program I've created.

How can I get all of the three VMs to see each other? This includes pinging each other sucessfully, able to share VMs shared folders to each other, and be able to access the Internet from the host itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either use nat or bridged network interface. either way the vms should all be in the same subnet and can ping each other and share resources as long as their firewall rules allow and shares are set up.

Comment: I see. However, when I used NAT, all of the three VMs share the same IPv4 Address. when I use BNI (Bridged Network Interface), it follows the DHCP Server Pool but they cannot ping each other [Always RTO - Request Time Out]. BTW, I'm always using a WiFi Broadband.

Comment: if the ip addresses are in the same subnet, then it is the firewall setup in the router. if they get ips in different subnets then things are much more complicated and you somehow have to route between the subnets.

Comment: The IP given to the VMs are in the subnet but exceeds the DHCP Pool Range. If I use BNI instead, how I am going to configure the Adapter so I could connect to the Internet using the VM.

Comment: if you use bridged, then the router for the host should route you to the internet, just like the host, because in this case the vm network is no different from its host.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was pertaining to Host-only adapter not BNI. I just can't get the BNI or NAT configuration release a different IPv4 Address for each of the VM. It's ok if the Internet can't be supported.